# Will an instance of this struct be allocated on the stack?

Tags: c#

This is my struct

```
public struct Timer
{
    private readonly float _duration;

    public float Time { get; private set; }

    public Timer(float duration)
    {
        _duration = duration;
        Time = duration;
    }

    public void Tick(float deltaTime)
    {
        if (Time == 0)
            return;
        
        Time -= deltaTime;

        if (Time < 0)
            Time = 0;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Time = _duration;
    }

}
```

It can be used by a class like so

```
public class Level : MonoBehavior
{
    private Timer _timer = new Timer(10f);
    
    private void Update()
    {
        _timer.Tick();

        if (_timer.Time == 0)
        {
            print("Time's up!");
        }
    }

}
```

Since the struct only contains value types, does that mean it will automatically be allocated to the stack when it gets instantiated by the other class?

Comment: No, the class object is stored in the GC heap.

Comment: yes, I guess however the method might cause an issue. have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/structs

Comment: In this context it will end up on the heap with the rest of the Level class. If it was, for example, a local variable inside a method it would be on the stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't be allocated on the stack. All members of the class are heap allocated, regardless of whether they are value types or not.

Comment: While this is mostly true, it's worth a deeper look at variable allocation: https://ericlippert.com/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/